# Android modbus library

Tags: android, bluetooth, modbus

Hi I must create an android app that sends modbus messages. However, I could not find a library for android that uses bluetooth as a transport layer. Does it exists?

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to figure out how to do this? Share it if you could.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure this question is still valid or not.

Normally, when people try to send Modbus message from android smartphone, they use either wireless or the USB port.

For wireless, you can just send a normal Modbus TCP message or Modbus Serial message encapsulated in TCP data packet.
For USB port, you will need to get a special USB to RS232 converter for smartphone.
http://www.pcables.com/

Never heard of any Modbus Application uses bluetooth to send Modbus message.
This is not really a good choice.